# Trying to validate that a radio button was selected

Tags: javascript

I've looked several places and can't find an example that works. In my example I select the radio group and test for null so I can issue a message telling the user to make a selection.

```
<script>                        
function validate(form) {   
    fail = validate__veteran(form);
    if (fail == "") { 
        return true;
        } else { 
            alert(fail);
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<script> 

    function validate_veteran(form) {
        var radios = document.getElementsById('veteran');
        if (radios == null) {
            return "please make a selection for veteran";
        }
        return "";
    }
</script>
<form method="post" action="checkbox.php" onSubmit="return validate(this)">
        Veteran?<**input type="radio" id="veteran"** name="veteran" value="veteran" /> yes <br>
                <input type="radio" id="veteran" name="veteran" value="" /> no <br>
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Signup" />                        
</form>
```

Comment: your code is a little buggy, there is no getElementsById, but getElementById

Comment: and if they are many, i suppose that what you're looking for is getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can use Jquery this can be achive in single line

```
    if ($('input[name=veteran]:checked').length <1) {
      alert("please make a selection for veteran");
return false;
    }
```

Comment: this presents me with an alert box but when I close it it proceeds to the php without letting me enter a selection.

Answer (score 2):

You can get checked status like this:

```
var radios = document.getElementById('veteran').checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Better would be, assign two different ID, to ur radio buttons, and check which is checked using

   ```
     document.getElementsById('ContorlID').checked
   ```

Or gng by ur code,  use value property

```
  function validate_veteran(form) {
       var radios = document.getElementsById('veteran');
       if (radios.value == "" {
         return "please make a selection for veteran";
       }
    return "";
  }
```

Comment: this presents me with an alert box but when I close it it proceeds to the php without letting me enter a selection.

Comment: It's too late in the evening my brain is shutting down I know this has to be simple I'll look at it in the morning.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Change You Form To:

```
<form method="post" name='myForm' action="checkbox.php" onSubmit="return validate(this)">
```

and

```
   <script>
    function validate_veteran(form) 
    var veteran="";
        for (var i=0; i < document.myForm.veteran.length; i++)
   {
   if (document.myForm.veteran[i].checked)
      {
      veteran = document.myForm.veteran[i].value;
      }
 return veteran
    }
    </script>
```